# Trying to shoot a projectile originating from a character in Pygame (with statement for all_sprites)

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to fire a projectile from a character, with that projectile being the mudball image. I have referenced my class MUDBALL to be included in all_sprites. In my first approach I get an error saying: AttributeError: 'TRUMP' object has no attribute 'rect' when I try and include MUDBALL in all_sprites. That approach is in the code below along with the Game class definitions. In the second approach I try and code the all_sprites statement into the  shoot method of the of the TRUMP class. I understand I only need one of these 2 pieces of code to work. I have tried to include the code necessary while omitting everything else to minimize confusion.

```
import pygame as pg

class Game:
  def __init__(self):
      # initialize game window, etc
      pg.init()
      pg.mixer.init()
      self.screen = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
      pg.display.set_caption(TITLE)
      self.clock = pg.time.Clock()
      self.running = True
      self.font_name = pg.font.match_font(FONT_NAME)
      self.load_data()

  def load_data(self):
       # load high score
       self.dir = path.dirname(__file__)
       img_dir = path.join(self.dir, 'img')
       with open(path.join(self.dir, HS_FILE), 'r') as f:
        try:
            self.highscore = int(f.read())
        except:
            self.highscore = 0
      # load spritesheet image
      self.spritesheet = Spritesheet(path.join(img_dir, SPRITESHEET))

def new(self):
      # start a new game
      self.score = 0
      self.all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
      self.platforms = pg.sprite.Group()
      self.player = Player(self)
      #ME: TRUMP added to all sprites!!!
      self.trump = TRUMP(self)
      self.all_sprites.add(self.trump)

      #***First attempt at adding mudball to all_sprites
      self.mudball = MUDBALL(TRUMP.rect.centerx, TRUMP.rect.centery)
      self.all_sprites.add(self.mudball)

      #game class continues...

class TRUMP(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
       pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
       self.game = game
       self.current_frame2 = 0
       self.last_update2 = 0
       self.load_images()

#TRUMP class continued etc... Second attempt with shoot def is below.

def shoot(self):
    mudball = MUDBALL(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery)
    Game.all_sprites.add(mudball)
     mudballs.add(mudball)

class MUDBALL(pg.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pg.image.load("MUDBALL.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speedx = -10

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.speedx
        # kill if moves off screen
        if self.rect.centerx < 0:
            self.kill
```

Shoot is a method of the TRUMP class! In second attempt I try and add MUDBALL to all sprites within the shoot definition of the TRUMP class. That doesn't work. again in this approach I take out the code from the previous approach. That attempt, which is just below, returns: NameError: name 'Game' is not defined. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  Specifically, show the entire error message (including line reference and flagged code) and all code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the missing **import** and corrected your indentation.  The problem still does not appear with the given code.  I'm sure that adding a main program to call something won't help, since your code is missing some definitions to be stand-alone executable.

Comment: Thanks very much! I don't know how to format in the window.

Comment: I corrected my copy, not yours.  I'll make the changes; please check me ... done now.

Comment: can you please verify whether my indentation updates are correct?  In particular, are **update** and **new** methods of class MUDBALL?  If not, you're missing a class -- or confusing the issue by using **self** in a non-standard way.

Comment: We're running in circles here: I need to understand your design and reproduce the problem before I can give you a reasonable amount of help.  When I can paste your code as given into a file here, run it, and reproduce your trouble, I'll work on understanding the question you're asking.  Please include comments that explain what you're trying to design.  For now, you're asking at the level of individual lines of code, and I still don't know what your classes and attributes are supposed to do -- so I can't answer your questions confidently.

Comment: I am trying to have an PNG(a mudball) go across the screen horizontally starting at my character. There is shoot function that when triggered executes the movement of the mudball. I will try and summarize the code I have written in another post. I have attempted to code the all_sprites function in both the Game class as well as in the shoot function. I can't get either to work. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be with your line

```
self.mudball = MUDBALL(self)
```

MUDBALL's **__init__** method requires x, y arguments; instead, you passed it an object and nothing.  That would be enough to cause the error you're seeing.

---

**Response to OP update:**

That's correct: **Game** is not defined.  That one line is the only place in your posted code where the symbol appears.  As you've coded this, you have the attachment backwards: **all_sprites** is an attribute (variable field) of **Game**.  In other words, **all_sprites** is attached to **Game**, not the other way around.  The only way to get to **all_sprites** is through **Game** ... except that **Game** isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: I try to pass MUDBALL with the following:                                                                                             self.mudball = MUDBALL(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.centery) But it says there is no attribute in 'rect' . Should I define rect in that section? Sorry for my lack of knowledge. thanks for pinpointing that!

Comment: This looks more applicable to the whole question; please put updates up there.

Comment: Excuse me I don't understand. I have a game class up there which I will now add to my code. Are you saying that I should code: all_sprites.game? This doesn't sound correct. I hope I can figure this out.

Comment: Update and new are methods of the game class.

Comment: One last time: if you want help, follow the posting guidelines.  I keep guiding you that way, but you keep ignoring me.  I'm not going to edit together comments and half-revealed problems trying to reproduce your errors: that's *your* job as poster.  When you provide the MCVE requested, I'll work on this again.

Comment: I even try:       self.mudball = MUDBALL(TRUMP.rect.centerx, TRUMP.rect.centery)
        self.all_sprites.add(self.mudball)

Comment: I would gladly send you my files because I cannot fit all my code on this page.

Comment: I still don't understand what is meant by game / attach statement? If I understand correctly the code is not suppose to go Game.all_sprites. But all_sprites.Game can't be right. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

A friend of mine helped me. He says "TRUMP is your class ... it does not have rect as an attribute only an instance of TRUMP will have rect as an attribute." I don't understand this yet. But want to thank everyone who helped me along.

self.mudball = MUDBALL(self.trump.rect.centerx, self.trump.rect.centery)
self.all_sprites.add(self.mudball)